# Using firebase to show all active page visitors on shopify site?

Tags: firebase, shopify, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to see if its possible to use Firebase to show the number of active users in real time on my shopify site. I also want to show the active users on a single product page if thats possible.

I see the Firebase example code for Presence but it looks like this only works for logged in users. How do I or is it even possible to show the real time user count ignoring whether someone is logged in or not...similar to the real time google analytics count?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase presence samples ([one](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-sample), [two](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-06-17-howto-build-a-presence-system.html), [three](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#example/presence)) all rely on the Firebase `onDisconnect()` handling. This method allows you to specify write/delete actions that should happen to your Firebase data on the server, once it detects that the connection to a client has been lost.

A system like this can work fine with using Firebase Authentication, but you need some way to uniquely identify each user. This can be any sufficiently random identifier, or for example the uid generate by Firebase's anonymous authentication. Both serve the same goal: authentication without identifications. That last approach is somewhat similar to how many analytics services work: they give you a unique ID when they first see you and then track you by that ID.